# Detect EF core 2.0 tooling from Startup.cs

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have some code in my Startup.cs of a MVC core 2.0 project that I only want to run when the app is actually started.

Is there a way of detecting when app is started from EF tools?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that with DotNet MVC Core 2.0 the answer lies in putting whatever code that should not be run by tooling, into program.cs main as the BuildWebHost is the only code executed by tooling.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        // Code placed here will not be executed by EF tooling as it calls BuildWebHost directly

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```